# applied optimization problem- triangle fence

Tags: calculus, optimization, triangles

A farmer is trying to fence off a field on the edge of a river. He has two 1km long sections of fence to use to make a triangular field. The edge by the river does not need fencing, and the fence creates an isosceles triangle. What is the base and height of the field that will yield the greatest possible area?

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula for the area $A$ of a triangle given the length of two sides $a$ and $b$ and the angle between them $C$:

$$ A = \frac 1 2ab\sin C $$

In your case, $a=b=1~\mathrm{km}$.

Since $\frac 1 2ab$ is a constant, in order to maximize $A$ we must maximize $\sin C$.  We know from trigonometry that the value of $\sin C$ is at most 1, and $\sin C=1$ when $C=\frac\pi 2=90\deg$.

Since the triangle is also isosceles, that means that we have a 45-45-90 triangle.  The hypotenuse is simply $\sqrt 2~\mathrm{km}$ and the height is half that, or $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}~\mathrm{km}$.

Comment: How do you find C though? Also how do you go from Area to base and height?

Comment: Well, $ C $ varies with different arrangements of the fences. But $ -1 \leq \sin C \leq 1 $ for all $ C $. So you want the value of $ C $ that maximises $ A $. That value of $ C $ will determine what the arrangement of your fences is.

Comment: Note that this very nice solution does not even require calculus.

Comment: I am suppose to solve it with calculus though… and thank you

Comment: Well, if you differentiate with respect to $C$ and set the derivative equal to $0$, you get $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Or you could let the base be $2x$ (the river side). Then the height is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and you are maximizing $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$, or equivalently $x^2(1-x^2)$. A little messier, not bad.